# How to set custom font for string array in grid view

Tags: java, android

I seem to not be able to figure out how to setup custom font for a string array.

```
String quizname[] = {"Cricket", "Football", "Tennis", "Golf", "Rugby", `"Hardcore",};`
```

I know how to set custom font for a text view like so but not sure how for a string in a grid view:

```
    Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "slant.TTF");
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("appPurchase", 0);
    editor = prefs.edit();
    textView.setTypeface(custom_font);
    textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gold));

    custGridList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < quizname.length; i++) {
        CustGridList list = new CustGridList();
        list.setQuizImg(imgs[i]);
        list.setQuizName(quizname[i]);
        custGridList.add(list);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to set different fonts for different items in RecyclerView?

Comment: Same font for each font in the recycle view with a text size of 18sp

Comment: Same font for each font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set font in recyclerView items in `onBindViewHolder`
Example:

```
class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView t;

        public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            t = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }
```

and in your `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, int position) {
      holder.t.setTypeface(custom_font);
}
```